# Search through column for multiple matching integers

Tags: python, pandas, search, dataframe

I'm trying to search through a database with a column that can have one or more integer values, to match one or more given integers. I just started using Python and Pandas.

The integers in the database has a '-' in between For example

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 1     | 1143              |
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 2     |1124-1123|
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 3     |1254-1234-1642      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I can't quite figure out how to parse the values, and at the same time make it so that order doesn't matter too. So let's say I have 1123 and 1124 as the two integers to find a match to, end goal here is to display the customer with the matching integers.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it a full match or a partial one?

Comment: I assume full match means say I have 1123 and 1124, then I have a customer with (1123-1124-1125) and another customer with (1123-1124). Only the second customer matters.
In that case yes full match

Comment: In that case [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45245126/4909087) would do it.

Comment: Actually how would you do a partial match? And how would you be able to differentiate when the customer a partial and when it's a full match?

Comment: Lethe regex will change. Check out the other answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245071/search-through-column-for-multiple-matching-integers?noredirect=1#comment77456899_45245071), I believe a full regex match is necessary. You can use [`df.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex pattern:

```
numbers = ['1124', '1123']
df

     Customer          Number
0  Customer 1            1143
1  Customer 2       1124-1123
2  Customer 3  1254-1234-1642
3  Customer 4  1124-1123-1125
```

```
df[df['Number'].str.match(f'{"-".join(numbers)}$')]  


     Customer     Number
1  Customer 2  1124-1123
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [174]: x
Out[174]:
         name              id
0  Customer 1            1143
1  Customer 2       1124-1123
2  Customer 3  1254-1234-1642

In [175]: pat = '|'.join(['1123', '1642'])

In [176]: x[x['id'].str.contains(pat)]
Out[176]:
         name              id
1  Customer 2       1124-1123
2  Customer 3  1254-1234-1642

In [177]: pat
Out[177]: '1123|1642'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to sets and use set logic then filter

```
s = set(['1123', '1642'])
df[df.id.str.split('-').apply(set) & s]

         name              id
1  Customer 2       1124-1123
2  Customer 3  1254-1234-1642
```

---

`pd.Series.str.split` creates a list of strings split on `'-'`

```
df.id.str.split('-')

0                [1143]
1          [1124, 1123]
2    [1254, 1234, 1642]
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Using `pd.Series.apply` with `set` converts those lists to sets

```
0                {1143}
1          {1123, 1124}
2    {1642, 1254, 1234}
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Then using `&` in a set context performs an element by element intersection

```
df.id.str.split('-').apply(set) & s

0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Which we then use to filter.

Answer (score 0):

try using pd.series.contains()

```
df1 = df[df['column_name'].str.contains('1123')]
```

if you want to find for 1123 and 1124 use join

```
list1 =['1123','1124']
listRegex = '|'.join(list1)
df1 = df[df['column_name'].str.contains(listRegex)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could parse the string using regex. I made an example using c# which you should have no problem porting over to python.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex("[1-9]+");

        string example = "1221-1231-4311-1236";

        Match match = regex.Match(example);

        while (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
```

Output is posted below, which you can do anything with.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, c# examples don't fly here.